# Angular binding not updating when data received from a service

Tags: angular, azure-ad-msal

In my Angular app, I use a service that gets the data from my API secured using OAuth2. I use [MSAL for Angular](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/blob/dev/lib/msal-angular/README.md) to authenticate the user.

When data is returned by the service for the first time after getting access token, binding is not updating in the component's template. This happens only after signing in to the app. If I refresh the page, binding works.

`MyComponent` code:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-mycomponent',
    template: '<span *ngIf="currentUser">{{currentUser.DisplayName}}</span>'
})
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
    public currentUser: User;

    constructor(private dataService: MyDataService) { }

    ngOnInit() {  
        this.dataService.getUser().subscribe((response: User) => {
            this.currentUser = response;  // this.curentUser is not updated in the template
            console.log(this.currentUser); // (1)
        }, (error) => { 
            console.error(error);
        }, () => {
            console.log(this); // (2)
        });
    }
}
```

`MyComponent` is placed in the `AppComponent`:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    template: '<app-mycomponent *ngIf="isAuthenticated"></app-mycomponent>
               <router-outlet></router-outlet>'
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
    public isAuthenticated: boolean;
    private msalSub: Subscription;

    constructor(
       private broadcastService: BroadcastService, 
        private authService: MsalService) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        if (this.authService.getUser()) {
            this.isAuthenticated = true;
        }

        this.msalSub = this.broadcastService.subscribe("msal:loginFailure", (payload) => {
            console.log("Login failure in AppComponent. " + JSON.stringify(payload));
            this.authService.loginRedirect();
        });

        this.msalSub = this.broadcastService.subscribe("msal:loginSuccess", (payload) => {
            console.log("Login success in AppComponent. " + JSON.stringify(payload));
        });
    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
        this.broadcastService.getMSALSubject().next(1);
        if (this.msalSub) {
            this.msalSub.unsubscribe();
        }
    }
}
```

`User` class:

```
export class User {
    Id: number;
    Guid: string;
    DisplayName: string;
}
```

`MyDataService`:

```
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MyDataService {
    private currentUser: User;

    constructor(private authService: MsalService, private http: HttpClient) { }

    public getUser(): Observable<User> {
        if (this.currentUser === undefined) {
            return this.httpGetRequest("https://localhost:1234/me/")
                .map((response: User) => {
                    this.currentUser = response;
                    return response;
                });
        } else {
            return Observable.of(this.currentUser);
        }
    }

    private httpGetRequest(url: string): Observable<object> {
        console.warn("GET: " + url);
        return this.http.get(url)
            .map(response => {
                console.log(response);
                return response;
            })
            .catch(response => (Observable.throw(response)))
    }
}
```

The console log (1) shows the user data received from the service and the last log (2) shows, that the component has `currentUser` property with correct data, but the value is not updated in the template.

(1) log output:

```
{Id: 1, Guid: "18740e56-1165-4e7c-ae27-1b4e2442cd43", DisplayName: "Test User"}
```

I looked into multiple other questions related to binding problems but I did not find any solution.

Comment: Can you post your service method and `User` interface / class

Comment: Can you try removing the *ngIf for debugging and see binding is working ? Also to trim down the issue you can manually inject ChangeDetectorRef in constructor and call this.cd.markForCheck(); normally we do this for onPush Detection strategy. the above steps will allow you to trim the down the issue.

Comment: @KurtHamilton I updated the question with the code you requested.

Comment: `console.log(this.currentUser); // (1)`  what is the result of this log ?

Comment: @LHIOUI A json object with data. See updated question.